# How to read the topics of a MSK cluster with React/TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, apache-kafka, aws-msk

I have been trying to read this data (Topics) to my MSK Cluster from my React application, I have found very few tools and information that can help me, and I have not succeeded

How can I get this data from MSK cluster and display them in a React table?

Some of the items I found: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-cdk/aws-msk, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/msk/latest/developerguide/client-access.html, https://akhq.io/, https://github.com/Microsoft/kafka-proxy-ws

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to read data from a topic using Javascript, you should take a look at the [kafkajs library](https://kafka.js.org/). You can use this library to create a consumer to read from your topic and then (in theory) you can output your data to  your React application.

You can make and run a basic consumer with the following code:

```js
const { Kafka } = require('kafkajs');

const kafka = new Kafka({
  clientId: 'my-app',
  brokers: ['broker1:9092', 'broker2:9092'],
});

const consumer = kafka.consumer({ groupId: 'consumer-group-id' });

await consumer.connect();

await consumer.subscribe({ topics: ['my-topic'] });

await consumer.run({
  eachMessage: async ({ topic, partition, message, heartbeat, pause }) => {
    // process your data here
  } 
});
```

Where you initialize this consumer and how you run it is up to you of course.

The [docs for consuming messages](https://kafka.js.org/docs/consuming) are pretty verbose as well, make sure to look over that for more info when you configure your consumer.

This link could also be helpful in structuring your project to use the consumer: https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/kafka-connect-react.rst

Comment: React (primarily) runs on a browser. [KafkaJS does not](https://kafka.js.org/docs/faq#can-kafkajs-be-used-in-a-browser). The other link seems specific to CData, rather than just plain Kafka connection

Answer (score -2):

First, `@aws-cdk/aws-msk` is a library to *provision a cluster*, not read from it.

React cannot consume from Kafka since it is client-side.

The AKHQ project (and similar Kafka GUI projects, like Confluent Control Center) generally use Java to render frontend HTML (AKHQ uses SSE with JSX, if you look at `TailController.java`) after using the native Java KafkaConsumer to poll a batch of records.

Basically, if your server and frontend are separate components, you need some type of proxy, such as the websocket from Microsoft (which has been archived so may no longer work with newer Kafka protocol versions), the Confluent REST Proxy, and/or your own backend server that is acting as a Kafka consumer that can expose messages to the frontend via some interface such as REST, GraphQL, WebSockets, or SSE.

The simplest solution, in my opinion, would be to [use the REST Proxy](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka-rest/api.html)

Comment: "React cannot consume from Kafka since it is client-side." This is incorrect. Applications have been using React for server-side rendering (or static-site generation, which could also theoretically benefit from Kafka) for years.

Comment: @JamesA.Rosen Theoretically? Do you have any specific examples? Kafka is dynamic, not static. Kafka doesn't have a websocket protocol or HTTP client bridge to the browser, is more what I meant, as I wrote in the answer

Comment: I definitely agree with the need for the proxy if accessing from the browser. But many React frameworks (metaframeworks?) have server-side data access patterns: fetch in RSC, getServerSideProps in Next, and loader in Remix.

Comment: @JamesA.Rosen Do you have any specific examples of how those can be used with the Kafka TCP protocol and not HTTP? (i.e. fetch cannot be used) And how that would actually work for a message queue? Not just rendered once at page load? And instead constantly polled? As answered, websockets or SSE is needed here, not just SSR